# factory-girl library in nestjs

Tags: typescript, factory, nestjs

I'm using factory-girl with nestjs

```
var factory = require('factory-girl');
factory = factory.factory;
@Injectable()
export class ChaptersService {

create(): void {

    factory.define('chapter', Chapter, {
        id: 1,
        name: 'test'
    });

    factory.build('chapter').then(chapter => {
        console.log(chapter);
    })
}
```

}

The problem here is the output object is empty

> Chapter {}

here is my chapter class

```
@Entity()
export class Chapter {
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
public id: number;
@Column({ nullable: true })
public name?: string;
@OneToMany(
    type => Course,
    course => course.chapter,
)
courses: Course[];
```

}

Comment: What is your `Chapter` object? Is it a model, a class, something else?

Comment: @Entity()
export class Chapter {
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
public id: number;
@Column({ nullable: true })
public name?: string;
@OneToMany(
    type => Course,
    course => course.chapter,
)
courses: Course[];
}

Comment: It looks like `factory-girl` works with `models` or `Objects` and not classes. Not 100% sure on that, but it seems there is an inconsistency in the use of the library